# Azure DevOps: Powershell 'Get-AzSubscription' is not recognized

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am deploying an ARM template from azure DevOps using Azure PowerShell as shown below.

[image]

This is subscription level deployment. I am getting below error.

> The term 'Get-AzSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Az
$context = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx
Set-AzContext $context


New-azdeployment -Name "SKL" -Location westeurope -TemplateFile .\delegatedResourceManagement.json -TemplateParameterFile .\delegatedResourceManagement.parameters.json
```

Logs:

```
##[section]Starting: Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 3.153.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell
==============================================================================
##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_6.7.0\AzureRM\6.7.0\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
##[command]Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction Stop
##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxx -TenantId ***
##[command]& 'd:\a\_temp\xxxxxxd.ps1' 
##[warning]User declined to install module (Az).
##[error]The specified module 'Az' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[error]The term 'Get-AzSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
##[section]Finishing: Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the task version: `4.* (Preview)` or higher to use the [Az powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.4.0) module:

[image]

Also there is an `Azure resource group deployment` to deploy ARM template easily:

[image]

Comment: As my templates will be deployed at the subscription level, Azure resource group deployment won't work. Task version=4.*(preview) worked.thanks.

Comment: Use Version 5 now

Answer (score 4):

looks like too much confusion among all az modules, MSFT have messed up az new/old  modules and are conflicting with each other. `az account show` will list all modules with AZ CLI

```
az account show
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Search apps and Features - Uninstall the old  April 2018 Azure
2. Follow something like this link  https://blog.atwork.at/post/The-new-Azure-PowerShell-Az-module

Then you won't have issue with

```
Get-AzSubscription   ( after using Connect)
```