# Get-AzWebApp : The term 'Get-AzWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function - Azure Devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to run below PowerShell script via azure devops pipeline()to add a new Private endpoint to my azure Vnet. Unfortunately I'm getting below error.

Error : Get-AzWebApp : The term 'Get-AzWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
#Starter pipeline
#Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
#Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
#https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1(XXXXXX)'
        scriptType: 'ps'
        scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
        scriptPath: 'PrivateEndpointTest.ps1'
```

**PrivateEndpointTest.ps1**

```
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName ENDPOINTTEST -Name anuendpointtest


## Create the private endpoint connection. ## 
$pec = @{
    Name = 'myConnection'
    PrivateLinkServiceId = $webapp.ID
    GroupID = 'sites'
}
$privateEndpointConnection = New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection @pec

## Place the virtual network you created previously into a variable. ##
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName 'ENDPOINTTEST' -Name 'VNET_ENDPOINT_TEST'

## Create the private endpoint. ##
$pe = @{
    ResourceGroupName = 'VNET_ENDPOINT_TEST'
    Name = 'myPrivateEndpoint'
    Location = 'North Europe'
    Subnet = $vnet.Subnets[0]
    PrivateLinkServiceConnection = $privateEndpointConnection
}
New-AzPrivateEndpoint @pe
```

Comment: Will the answer above solve your issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055269/azure-devops-powershell-get-azsubscription-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the `Azure PowerShell task` and select the latest version.

Azure CLI requires run command below as administrator:

```
Install-Module Az 

Import-Module Az
```

If you want to use Azure CLI, consider using Self-host agent.

[Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172102/connect-azaccount-the-term-connect-azaccount-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-o) for  your reference.

Comment: Using Azure PowerShell task, I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: I am trying front door related calls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.frontdoor/?view=azps-10.4.1#front-door  but all of them are giving same error and all modules are available like Az.FrontDoor etc.